# Does it take less time for the program to read a literal or to interpret a variable?

Tags: c++

Does it take less time for the program to read a literal than reading a variable?
Let's say that we have these scenarios:

```
std::cout << 24 + 55 << endl;
```

and this one:

```
int x = 24;
int y = 55;
std::cout << x + y << endl;
```

So does it take some extra time for the program when having to read these variables and interpret them instead of just reading the literals?
I am an over-thinker I guess... 
Thanks!

Comment: The compiler will almost always optimize them into the same code.

Comment: When the observable effect is identical, there's always a good chance that the compiler compiles it into the very same binary code. Have you looked at the two executables? Do they differ?

Comment: A compiled C++ program doesn't "read" or "interpret" the source code when it's executing.

Comment: But doesn't the program first have to find the variables in the memory and then get the value of those addresses? Doesn't that take some extra time?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/RZS4xg

Comment: You *are* overthinking this. :-) Even if there is a difference, we are talking nanoseconds.

Comment: Just look at the binaries. It will help you

Comment: It takes more time for a program to execute `std::cout << std::endl` than it does to execute `std::cout << '\n'`. Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is optimized, they will most likely generate exactly the same code. The compiler can see that the variables are never modified, so it substitutes their values into the `cout` code.

If it's not optimized, the literals will probably be faster. The compiler will put immediate data in the instructions, and probably do the addition at compile time. The variables may have to be loaded from memory locations into registers.

If you want to know for sure, use the `-S` option to the compiler to save the assembler code to a file, and look at how each version of the function is compiled.